# jQuery Table Columns / Rows Hide or Change color

Tags: jquery, html, datatable, html-table

Right now I am playing with an idea where I want to change the color (maybe eventually remove/hide) a column or row of data right now my aim is the columns. So far I have it partly working but not entirely

with this:

```
$('#'+arry[0]+' tr td:eq('+arry[1]+')').css({"background-color":"FF0"});
```

I am able to effect the column but only one row, not all rows within that column, and it seems to be effecting the rows/columns within the "tbody" but not the "thead" or "tfoot" I need to effect all 3.

an example of the table I am working with looks like:

```
<table id="testerTable">
    <thead>
        <th>First</th>
        <th>Second</th>
        <th>Third</th>
        <th>Fourth</th>
        <th>Fifth</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm thinking my approach is to simple, so I need some ideas. This will ultimately be used with datatables from datatables.net but first I need to figure out this part.

****EDIT****

The `arry` variable is currently take from the rel attribute of something else `arry[0]` is the tables id.. and `arry[1]` is the position of the column in this case 0-4

Comment: how looks the arry ? What is the 'position of the column'?

Comment: edited to show. But in the attribute mentioned it looks like testerTable::2 for example

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. look below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### *[demo jsBin](http://jsbin.com/oremav/edit#javascript,html,live)*

```
var string= 'testerTable::2'; // your data // test with: 0,1,2,3,4
var arry= string.split('::'); // split to separate values

var $tr = $('#'+arry[0]+' tr');


$('#'+arry[0]+' th').eq(arry[1]).css({"background-color":"FF0"});

$tr.each(function(el){ // iterate through all 'tr' to find relative 'td' .eq()
  $(this).find('td').eq(arry[1]).css({"background-color":"FF0"});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `<colgroup>` to color the columns as it would be quick and easy to manipulate.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_col.asp

An example, you could put:

```
<colgroup>
  <col style="background-color:FF0" />
  <col span="4" />
</colgroup>
```

and edit the entire colgroup with jquery or other means.

Comment: unfortunately colspan isn't supported by datatables, and can't be used currently. I wish it was as easy as colspan for me :-)

Comment: @chris hmm, I just read a comment on their website that said the same thing (oh, about colgroup, not colspan), but they say nothing bad will happen if you use it. Maybe they should think about it.

Comment: most of the tables I work with are dynamically generated through datatables, so adding in the col (group/span) is a bit more difficult all around (maybe not so much on newer tables we generate, but existing ones through out the sys), overall trying to come up with a solution to cover all bases.

Answer (score 0):

You could just give each element in column 1 the class 'c1' and then do $('.c1').css...  This would save mucking about with th/tr/td distinctions. You'd do this for every column, of course.

And BTW, it's spelt 'array' :)

Comment: i know its spelled array but the variable name I gave is arry when I defined it through the spilt I did on the original attribute :) Ill have to see if datatables supports the notion of classing every column like that

Comment: Glad to know about the spelling :) Giving classes to table elements works fine, too, so you can do it this way, should you wish to.

Comment: You can't do it in one hit per column, though. You'd have to add the class to each td element.